# Android google maps not displaying on another machine

Tags: android, google-maps

I am new to android. I worked on a different machine to develop my app. Now I moved everything to new machine. Everything works fine except the google maps. I see following errors in LogCat.

> Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers. This is probably an authentication issue

Please help me in resolving this.

Thanks

Comment: Try to generate new key. The key is system specific

Comment: You need to generate a New `API Key`.....

Comment: How can I do that? This project was actually started by someone else and he is on a vacation.

Comment: Just generate new api key from your project keystore using command line "keytool -list -v -keystore your keystore"and put new key on google console account.

Comment: The app is already on the playstore. I have the API key from google console. Not sure why I need to create another key. Can you please explain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to generate a New `API Key` because you change the system so that your **SHA-1** also gonna be changed. So, generate a New key and try..

Comment: also what we usually do within the team - we share debug.keystore between team members, so you don't need to have separate key for each machine

Comment: @PavelDudka In that case it's fine....you'll have same debug.keystore...so no need to generate a New key

Comment: @ M D: So you mean I can simply replace my debug.keystore with the old one. Will that help?

Comment: @ankith No.men i am not talking about replacement.

Comment: @ankith actually yes:) just try to replace debug.keystore with the one you used for generating API key - it should work fine

Answer (score 0):

Try to generate new key. The key is system specific. Once the app is published you don't need to do this in every system though.

System specific: This is because of the key you generated using terminal